# Create ggplot2 function and specify arguments as variables in data as per ggplot2 standard functionality

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a plotting function where I specify the data set, and specify the plotting arguments as function arguments in similar fashion as I can within `ggplot2`, i.e. where we specify the variable name without the dataset, e.g. `hp` instead of `mtcars$hp`.

For example:

```
ggfun <- function(dat, x.var, y.var){

  ggp <- ggplot(data = dat,
                aes(x = x.var,
                    y = y.var)) +
    geom_point()

  return(ggp)
}


ggfun(dat = mtcars, x.var = drat, y.var = hp)
```

Would return:
[image: wonderful plot]

However it returns:

```
> ggfun(dat = mtcars, x.var = drat, y.var = hp)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'drat' not found
In addition: Warning message:
In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : restarting interrupted promise evaluation
```

I know [using `aes_string` instead of `aes` works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49948143/2706826), e.g.:

```
ggfun <- function(dat, x.var, y.var){

  ggp <- ggplot(data = dat,
                aes_string(x = x.var,
                    y = y.var)) +
    geom_point()

  return(ggp)
}

ggfun(dat = mtcars, x.var = "drat", y.var = "hp")
```

But I'd prefer to avoid using string form.

Other attempts include `ggfun(dat = mtcars, x.var = mtcars$drat, y.var = mtcars$hp)`, which returns the right graph but partially defeats the purpose of the exercise, and produces lables "x.var" and "y.var" instead of "drat" and "hp".

Any known *and reasonably simple* way around this?

Comment: I would also suggest @akrun's solution below.  I would like to add that a great resource on understand how to work with unquoted variables is https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html   `ggplot2` was originally developed before this the `rlang` package became an integral part of tidyverse, and so it's being rewritten (has been?) to support quosures - hence you will need to download ggplot2 from github to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of [`rlang` 0.4.0](https://rlang.r-lib.org/news/index.html#rlang-040) (2019-06-25) there is now the [embrace operator](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/embrace-operator.html) `{{}}`. With the embrace operator:

```
library(ggplot2)
data("mtcars")
```

The operator works with both column names and labels in function arguments.

```
scatter_plot <- function(data, x, y, title) {
  ggplot(data, aes({{x}}, {{y}})) +
    geom_point()+
    labs(title= {{title}})
}
```

```
scatter_plot(mtcars, drat, hp, "Drat by HP")
```

Plots can be further customized with `+` just as normal.

```
scatter_plot(mtcars, drat, hp, "Drat by HP with trend") +
  geom_smooth()
```

### Other resources

- [This](https://thomasadventure.blog/posts/turning-your-ggplot2-code-into-a-function/) post is where I encountered the method.
- This SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62792494/13110995) provides some additional very similar examples of using tidy evaluation with `dplyr` and tables.

Answer (score 24):

With the devel version of `ggplot2`, we can pass unquoted arguments, convert it to `quosure` (with `enquo`) and evaluate it (`!!`)

```
ggfun <- function(dat, x.var, y.var){
  x.var <- enquo(x.var)
  y.var <- enquo(y.var)
  ggp <- ggplot(data = dat,
                aes(x = !! x.var,
                    y = !! y.var)) +
    geom_point()

  return(ggp)
}

ggfun(dat = mtcars, x.var = drat, y.var = hp)
```

For quoted strings, convert it to symbol with `sym` (from `rlang`) and do the evaluation

```
ggfun <- function(dat, x.var, y.var){
  x.var <- rlang::sym(x.var)
  y.var <- rlang::sym(y.var)
  ggp <- ggplot(data = dat,
                aes(x = !! x.var,
                    y = !! y.var)) +
    geom_point()

  return(ggp)
}

ggfun(dat = mtcars, x.var = "drat", y.var = "hp")
```

[image]

---

If we want to pass either quoted or unquoted, the quosure is changed to character (`quo_name`), then to symbol (`sym`) and evaluate (`!!`)

```
ggfun <- function(dat, x.var, y.var){
  x.var <- rlang::sym(quo_name(enquo(x.var)))
  y.var <- rlang::sym(quo_name(enquo(y.var)))
  ggp <- ggplot(data = dat,
                aes(x = !! x.var,
                    y = !! y.var)) +
    geom_point()

  return(ggp)
}

p1 <- ggfun(dat = mtcars, x.var = drat, y.var = hp)
p2 <- ggfun(dat = mtcars, x.var = "drat", y.var = "hp")

all.equal(p1, p2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Are the calls to `rlang` required for any ggplot() functions we might build?  I'm writing a function to contain a lot of `annotate` arguments...