# ggplot resulting in error in function but working fine outside

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, scatter-plot

```
myfunc   <- function(my_df,colmn) {
  if (lapply(my_df[colmn], is.numeric) == TRUE){
    print(class(my_df[colmn])) #Checking to see if I'm getting dataframe
    print(colmn) #Check to see if I'm getting the right column

    #Plotting a scatter plot
    ggplot(data=my_df,
           aes(x =my_df[colmn], #x-axis being the input colmn value via the function
               y=my_df["colmn2"] # a column that is already present in the my_df dataframe
               )
           ) +
      geom_point(size=2)
  }
}

myfunc(my_df=a_df, colmn="colmn1")
```

Output -

```
[1] "data.frame"
[1] "colmn1"
```

Error -

> Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type
>   data.frame. Defaulting to continuous. Don't know how to automatically
>   pick scale for object of type data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.
>   Error in is.finite(x) : default method not implemented for type 'list'

If I executed the ggplot outside of the function(below code), I get nice looking scatter plot without any error

```
ggplot(data=a_df, aes(x=a_df$colmn1,y=a_df$colmn2)) + geom_point(size=2)
```

I'm not sure why the values are defaulting to continous and why is.finite(x) coming up

EDIT - I tried  `x=col`, `x=my_df$col` and `x=my_df[col]` formats in aes()

Comment: In the aes function, you don't need to repeat the dataframe name because it's already specified in the data= argument. Have you tried aes(x=colmn, ...)?

Comment: Try passing strings (without referring to the dataset) with `aes_string()`, `aes_string(x = colmn, y = "colmn2")` or use the `.data` pronoun (using tidyeval from **rlang**), `aes(x = .data[[colmn]], y = .data[["colmn2"]])`).  `aes_string()` is the "old way" of using ggplot2 in a function, and I believe it is now deprecated in favor of tidyeval.

Comment: There are other question/answers out there that this is related to, but [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50960339/create-ggplot2-function-and-specify-arguments-as-variables-in-data-as-per-ggplot) was the newest one I found searching "r ggplot2 in a function".

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the *[]* is not working within the **aes()** arguments

This should work:

```
MyData <- mtcars #Just to gain some reproducibility in the example. 

myfunc   <- function(my_df,colmn) {
 if (lapply(my_df[colmn], is.numeric) == TRUE){
   print(class(my_df[colmn])) 
   print(colmn) 

   #Create an additional object to store your variables
   DataTemp <- data.frame(my_df[colmn], my_df["mpg"])
   names(DataTemp) <- c("X", "Y")

#Plot the scatter plot using the created object
ggplot(data = DataTemp,
       aes(x = X, 
           y = Y )) +
  geom_point(size=2) }}

myfunc(my_df = MyData, colmn="gear")
```