# passing data as arguements of a function in R

Tags: r

Super noob question but I cant find the answer. Dont understand why the variable reference isnt working.  Would appreciate if anyone could forward me to a post where I could learn about this.   Thanks

```
factor_check <- function(x,y) {
   unique(x$y)
}

factor_check(data , variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$` operator is not as flexible as the `[` operator for subsetting. There you can pass a string as a column name to do what you're looking for. From `?Extract`:

> Both `[[` and `$` select a single element of the list. The main difference is that `$` does not allow computed indices, whereas `[[` does. `x$name` is equivalent to `x[["name", exact = FALSE]]`.

So, for your example that would look something like:

```r
f <- function(dat, col) {dat[[col]]}

f(mtcars, "cyl")
#>  [1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could use the embrace operator with dply::pull(), if you need to pass cyl without quotation marks. Links below explain the rlang operator.

```
factor_check <- function(x,y) {
   unique( dplyr::pull(x, {{y}} ))
}
factor_check(mtcars, cyl)
```

https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/embrace-operator.html

[What is the "embracing operator" `{{ }}`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62791997/what-is-the-embracing-operator)

Comment: appreciate it ill check this out